# Python Mixins: *args/**kwargs vs explicit call to `__init__`

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, mixins

I try to write an example of Mixins using `Clickable` and `Rectangle` classes, which are superclasses of the `Button` class.

Currently I use:

```py
class Clickable:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.clicks = 0

    def click(self):
        self.clicks = self.clicks + 1


class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, x0, y0, x1, y1, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.upper_right = (x0, y0)
        self.lower_down = (x1, y1)


class Button(Clickable, Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I consider using:

```py
class Clickable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clicks = 0

    def click(self):
        self.clicks = self.clicks + 1


class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, x0, y0, x1, y1):
        self.upper_right = (x0, y0)
        self.lower_down = (x1, y1)


class Button(Clickable, Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, x0, y0, x1, y1):
        Rectangle.__init__(self, x0, y0, x1, y1)
        Clickable.__init__(self)
```

Is one of them is better for some reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way (see https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) is to use keyword arguments to avoid conflicts between which parent is expected to be passed which positional arguments.

```
class Clickable:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.clicks = 0

    def click(self):
        self.clicks = self.clicks + 1


class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, x0, y0, x1, y1, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.upper_right = (x0, y0)
        self.lower_down = (x1, y1)


class Button(Clickable, Rectangle):
    # No need to override __init__ if all it does
    # is pass all its arguments to the next invocation
    pass


b = Button(x0=0, y0=0, x1=10, y1=10)
```

Remember, the reason for accepting arbitrary keyword arguments and passing them on in the first place is that you don't know which class `super()` will produce, so you can't predict the expected signature.

Mixins are nearly, by definition, expected to support cooperative inheritance, because they are expected to be used with multiple inheritance and *someone* will probably want to use your mixin in a class that does.